# Cannot read numbers in XCode 8 from UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to ask for patient's age and check if he/she is adult. How ever, it always returns false (parameter is always less than 18)!!
Here is the code:

```
var index = 0
    let patAge = Double(txtAge.text!)
    if (txtAge.text?.characters.count == 0){
        index = 0
        while index < medicationMenuItems.count{
            medicationMenuItems[index].medicationName = medicationNames[index]
            index += 1
        }
    } else {
        if (patAge?.isLess(than: 18))!{
            index = 0
            while index < medicationMenuItems.count{
                medicationMenuItems[index].medicationName = medicationNames[index] + ": Adult?"
                index += 1
            }
        }
    }
    tableViewMedications.reloadData()
```

Generally: how can I read text into doubles?? And how can I convert calculations to strings??
I am trying also to set a text in text field from double, but it is either returning an error or returning an "Optional(TextGoesHere)", where it should give "TextGoesHere" only:

```
let temporaryString = String(doubleValue)
txtAge.text = temporaryString
```

It returns an error, that I should give "String(describing: doubleValue)!!!

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you really need `Double` for an *age* ?

Comment: Why don't use int instead of Double and simply check if (value < 18)

Comment: Regardless of whether you use `Double(string)` or `Int(String)` it returns an optional (the string may be unable to be parsed) so you need to unwrap it via `if let ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vadian mentioned you should be using an Int, unless you need a part age for whatever reason. Also, when checking the character count of a string, i highly recommend you call this instead of what you have if you are using a normal keyboard:

```
txtAge.text?.replace(" ", replacement: "").characters.count
```

in order to prevent any further errors.

Secondly rather than wrapping the double like this:

```
String(doubleValue)
```

you should do this instead:

```
txtAge.text = "\(doubleValue)"
```

if you are adamant on having it remain a double, perhaps consider converting it into an int first if you want to show a whole number, rather than a number with a decimal.

Comment: Thanks! Worked! Although replace is not present in Swift 3!

Comment: if my answer worked, would you mind clicking the check mark please? :D

Answer (score 1):

One comment is that I am not sure what your intention is converting the 'age' to a Double. This should almost certainly be an integer.

> how can I read text into doubles?

This works.

```
var ageText = "17" 
var ageAsDouble = Double(ageText)
```

But really you probably want this if your working with age as a whole number:

```
let minimumAge = 18
var ageText = 17
var age = Int(age)
if (age! < minimumAge) {
    print("must be older than 18!")
}
```

> And how can I convert calculations to strings??

This works.

```
var str = String(ageAsDouble!)
print("printing string value", str)
```

I am by no means a swift expert but what you need to understand is when optional values are involved the value may or may not exist. For example if you try to pass the string "32f" to the Double init there will be no way to create the Double. So if you do:

```
var ageText = "32f"
var age = Double(ageText)
then do..
print(age!)
```

It will certainly error, this is because the value is nil. The forced optional unwrap is telling the program to "Unwrap this value because I am 100% sure its not nil!"

Comment: The whole 1st half of your answer doesn't apply because the OP is trying to convert text entered in by the user into a `Double`. Your code is dealing with `Int`, not `String`.

Comment: Sorry rmaddy, I was trying to provide code examples for both to explain how OP would do this if he actually wanted an Int and didn't know it. Is it bad to provide code examples for both instances? I just realized there was a typo on the "var ageText" line... oops

Comment: But the OP isn't trying to convert an `Int` into a `Double` and doesn't need to at all.

Comment: Now you need to deal with the fact that `ageAsDouble` will be an optional.

Comment: Ill let you take that one rick